# Issue with draggable and resizable for same element

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I've been doing some research about draggable & resizable plugins from jQuery but encountered an issue recently. I've tried to replicate this situation on the following fiddle:

```
$('.event').draggable({
grid: [120, 12],
cursor: 'move',
containment: '#container',
start: function (event, ui) {
    console.log("event dragging started");
}
}).resizable({
containment: 'parent',
grid: 12,
handles: {
    'n': '#ngrip',
        's': '#egrip'
},
start: function (e, ui) {
    console.log('resizing started');
},
```

});

Here's [a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/flaszer/M2umR/2/).

The resizable south handle doesn't work at all, also the strange thing happens to the north handle -> it decreases size of my div an pushes it rapidly to the right.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: After I debug your code, found something. Did you mistype the s handles ? #egrip or #sgrip ?

Comment: And I found If I update the grid to 18 or more , It works fine.

Comment: And I suggest you download the debug version of jquery.ui. try to debug the resize event handle. I am sure it will be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Your code:**

```
$('.event').draggable({
    grid: [120, 12],
    cursor: 'move',
    containment: '#container',
    start: function (event, ui) {
        console.log("event dragging started");
    }
}).resizable({
    containment: 'parent',
    grid: 12,
    handles: {
        'n': '#ngrip',
            's': '#egrip'
    },
    start: function (e, ui) {
        console.log('resizing started');
    },

});
```

**Code Needed**

```
$('.event').draggable({
    grid: [120, 12],
    cursor: 'move',
    containment: '#container'
}).resizable({
    containment: 'parent',
    grid: [ 120, 12 ],
    handles: "n, e, s, w"

});
```

1) remove trailing comma in the end
2) make handles as `handles: "n, e, s, w"`
 but there is still some bug after this you can only resize after you have dragged from once and resizing work precisely from a pixel maybe because you are using custom resize handlers, I am not sure.  Read the [documentation](http://api.jqueryui.com/resizable/) for more help.

**New Code**

```
$('.event').draggable({
    cursor: 'move',
    containment: '#container'
}).resizable({
    containment: '#container',
    handles:"n, e, s, w",
    start: function (e, ui) {
        console.log('resizing started');
    }
});
```

Comment: I think it has nothing to do event with the comma as well as with custom handles. I have applied your suggestions and it's still the same, wrong behaviour: http://jsfiddle.net/flaszer/M2umR/8/

Comment: I've check your code and still, moving top handle of the second column's event moves it immediately out of the screen. Also there is something that I didnt mention before but existed - resizable containment is not respected properly, I'm able to resize my div outside it's container.

Comment: you can remove the grid check this: http://jsfiddle.net/M2umR/9/
somehow grid is making the draggable event going to the right after the bound

Comment: Exactly, that is what I have also observed. Unfortunately, it is neccesary for me to have this grid.

Comment: You can check this link: http://jsfiddle.net/M2umR/10/
but the issue is when you provide a grid greater than height of the containment container it goes beyond that and you get the overflow bug, so try give a smaller grid.

Comment: Ok, you are right, event is not dissapearing now. Maybe do You know why I'm able to resize my div outside the container?

Comment: I tried do replicate it again but even i have no idea, may be due to some grid numbers but not sure.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code.
Jquery

```
    $(document).ready(function (){
       $('.blue').resizable();
       $(".blue").draggable();
    });
```

Html

```
    <div id="container">
       <div class="column">
          <div class="event blue">
           </div>
       </div>
        <div class="column">
          <div class="event dark-blue blue"  id="event" style="margin-top:3px">
          </div>
        </div>
     </div>
```

Attach jquery files

```
<script type="text/javascript"
src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"
src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css"/>
```

Comment: Yes, with this simple code everything would work, because the problem I think is caused by using grid option, so doesn't solve my issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code i think this will helpful you

Html:

```
<div id="container">
 <div class="column">
    <div class="event blue">
        <div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-n" id="ngrip"></div>
        <div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-s" id="sgrip"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="column">
    <div class="event dark-blue"  id="event" style="margin-top:3px">
        <div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-n" id="ngrip"></div>
        <div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-s" id="sgrip"></div>
    </div>
</div>
 </div>
</div>
```

jquery:

```
    $(document).ready(function (){
     $('.blue').resizable({
           handles: {
               's': '#sgrip',
                'w': '#wgrip'
            }
         });
        $('.dark-blue').resizable({
        handles: {
           's': '#sgrip',
            'w': '#wgrip'
          }

      });
    $(".column").draggable();
   });
```

Answer (score 0):

Fix it . Please review it .

```
$('.event').draggable({
    grid: [120, 12],
    cursor: 'move',
    containment: '#container',
    start: function (event, ui) {
        console.log("event dragging started");
    }
}).resizable({
    containment: '#container',
    grid: 12,
    handles: {
        'n': '#ngrip',
            's': '#sgrip'
    },
    start: function (e, ui) {
        console.log('resizing started');
    },

});
```

change the resizable containment from `parent` to `#container`, and south handle name from `#egrip` to `#sgrip`. nothing else.

check fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/malaikuangren/sdZtL/1/).